# Is there a way to check if a symbol is a built-in variable?

Tags: variables, builtin

This is how you check if an object is a built-in function:

```lisp
(subrp (symbol-function 'assoc))
=> t
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this for variables as well?

Comment: I suppose `(help-C-file-name SUBR-OR-VAR KIND)` is the best we've got

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "built-in" you mean a variable defined in C.  This should do it:

```lisp
(defun built-in-var-p (variable)
  "Return non-nil if VARIABLE is defined in C source code."
    (let ((file-name  (find-lisp-object-file-name variable 'defvar)))
      (and file-name  (eq file-name 'C-source))))
```

Comment: Internally, `find-lisp-object-file-name` calls `help-C-file-name`. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @JohnDeBord: No, not that I know of. I basically took this code from `describe-variable` etc. in `help-fns.el`. Please consider adding your comment that suggests `help-C-file-name` as an answer! Thx.